# Using RestSharp to submit a POST request, values are added to header

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to submit some data to an API using RestSharp in C# and it seems all of my parameters are added to the Headers collection - or that is just how they are catalogued in VS.

Here is my code

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.com");
var request = new RestRequest("/recognize", Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("app_id", "");
request.AddHeader("app_key", "");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

request.AddParameter("gallery_name", model.gallery_name);
request.AddParameter("image", model.image);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

The error back from the API says the request is missing the gallery_name and image parameters, but looking into the request object they are there in the Headers collection.

I can make the call in Postman where the method is set to Post and the Body is set to form-data, along with 2 key/value pairs listed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use AddHeader instead of AddParameter for those two?

Comment: Why would that work? AddHeader is adding to the header, and AddParameter is also adding to the header

Comment: Unsure, just wondered if you had tried it. It shouldn't make any difference, but how often has that stopped wierd stuff from happening?

Comment: Also what format is the image in as model.image? is it a url, base64?

Comment: This behaviour appears to be correct according to [the RestSharp documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest#getorpost) - which says that given that this is a POST, a GetOrPost type parameter will be rendered in the body, **unless the request is multipart/form-data**.

Answer (score 6):

In your question you says "I can make the call in Postman ...".

Normally if the Postman request is successful then should the generated RestSharp code from Postman works, if there are no open issues in the RestSharp library that can cause your problem.

It's hard to debug and reproduce the problem from here, but I can give the following that you can check.

**Check this:**

If your Postman request works and is successful then check the Restsharp code generated by Postman:

1. Click on "code"

[image: Step 1: Get the generated code from Postman]

2. Choose in the combobox for "C# (RestSharp)"

[image: See the Restsharp code from the postman request]

3. Try the RestSharp code that you see in the window, if the code doesn't work check this [URL](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues) for known issues.

On a sidenote: If you see a known issue that can cause your error, try to test with a previous version of RestSharp or an [alpha version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/).

I hope you can now further investigate and debug the problem.

(I had similar problems and resolved it successful with this way of investigating and debugging)